# Combo-box repeats options

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox

I am new to using flash, so sorry if this is a common problem - but I couldn't figure out what to search.

I've created a pretty basic movie - which uses a combo-box to switch between some images. [See Here](http://www.sampassmore.com/flashdemographic.swf).

The problem is when you click off the first option ("Gender") to another option and then return to Gender, the list of options in the combobox repeats.

I was wondering if there was a way to stop this from happening? 
I have this problem both in my browser and in Flash Professional CS5.5

The actionscript code I have at the moment is;

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop(); 

combobox.addItem( { label: "Gender" } );
combobox.addItem( { label: "Ethnicity" } );
combobox.addItem( { label: "Religion" } );

combobox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeimage);

function changeimage (event:Event):void{
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Gender") gotoAndStop(1);
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Ethnicity") gotoAndStop(2);
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Religion") gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `ComboBox` in a `Main Class`. Do File > New > ActionScript File, and copy / paste the following code in this new file. Name it: `Main`.

**Main.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.controls.ComboBox;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var cb:ComboBox;

        public function Main()
        {
            cb = new ComboBox();
            cb.addItem({label:'Gender', data:1});
            cb.addItem({label:'Ethnicity', data:2});
            cb.addItem({label:'Religion', data:3});
            cb.move(120, 160);
            cb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, labelSelected);
            addChild(cb);
        }
        private function labelSelected(e:Event):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(cb.selectedItem.data);
        }
    }
}
```

In your Flash document, do: File > ActionsScript Settings > Documment Class: `Main`.

---

Otherwise you can create your labels in your `ComboBox`'s occurence physically present on the stage using the window `Properties`.

You just have to use the `Component` menu in the `Properties` panel of your `ComboBox`. You select the pencil in front of the property `DataProvider`. It will open a window `Values`...

[image]

...in which you could add your labels with the button `plus`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your first suggestion worked in that the combobox no longer repeats - however, the new combobox is in the upper left corner and is not present on the stage like my previous box - so I cannot click and move it to the appropriate place. Do you know why this is? I have uploaded an example up to the same link as above.

Comment: @SamPassmore - You just have to use `move` method: cb.move(x, y). I've edited my answer with arbitrary coordinates. The second solution also works with your ComboBox on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

You may encapsulate your addItem in a function :

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop(); 
function initializeComboBox(){
    combobox.addItem( { label: "Gender" } );
    combobox.addItem( { label: "Ethnicity" } );
    combobox.addItem( { label: "Religion" } );

    combobox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeimage);
}

function changeimage (event:Event):void{
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Gender") gotoAndStop(1);
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Ethnicity") gotoAndStop(2);
    if (combobox.selectedItem.label == "Religion") gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

And call this function when the initialize event is fired.
I hope i'm clear enough.